# redirect Apache .httacces 301 and PHP 301

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

most guide across the Internet using Apache, but i find PHP is easier.

is redirect with Apache .httacces 301 or PHP 301 is same? 
pros? cons?

for SEO friendly esp Google.

:) thanks.

Comment: Both php header() and .htaccess will simply sent back a header. Same thing for both, just do it the way you like

Comment: @John thanks that makes clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most "accepted" way to do this is with Apache `.htaccess` as `PHP` *can* fail (bad code etc.) You may not always be aware of problems that could cause your script to not run.  In a perfect world they would be identical.  But being that you can't always **know** for certain your PHP will serve, Apache is a guarantee.

Comment: bad code can also happen in .htaccess. The only advantage above php is the overhead. PHP need to be parsed with php. But this overhead is so small that it does not matter.

Comment: @John, `bad code can also happen in .htaccess`  --  I agree, however 99% of the time you'll get a Server Error right away.  With PHP this is not always the case.  Stranger things have happened than the intermittent fatal PHP error.

Comment: I'm stills new. what do you mean fail?
at first using PHP come with error, but after use ob_start(),ob_flush() seems fine.

Comment: All I am saying, in PHP be careful with redirects.  Make sure your error handling is correct and that the page will always serve to the best of your ability.  I personally use this guide: http://www.nyphp.org/phundamentals/7_PHP-Error-Handling on a regular basis.  Like I said they are identical other than the fact PHP is not a guarantee and is only as reliable as you make the 'rest' of your code.  an .htaccess file is a lot less complex (no extensive functions, object, etc.) and therefore less prone to mistakes or errors once functioning correctly.